# The independence "one from the other": an adverbial phrase?

Tags: adverbials

This question is [originally posted on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326594/the-independence-one-from-the-other-an-adverbial-phrase). I repost it here on EL&U mutatis mutandis following the [advice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326594/the-independence-one-from-the-other-an-adverbial-phrase#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20fairly%20advanced%20linguistics%20question%2C%20and%20might%20be%20better%20suited%20to%20EL%26U%20or%20Linguistics.SE) I got there.

This is the sentence in question from *The Cambridge Companion to Chomsky* by James McGilvray:

> Evidence for both kinds of modularity comes from **the independence one from the other** of the various modules, as seen most clearly in double dissociation.

Which appears in this context below:

> [...] there are two different notions of modularity:
> one according to which the language faculty is a module of the mind, distinct from moral judgment, music, and mathematics; another according to which the language module itself divides up into submodules, relating to sound, structure, and meaning. Evidence for both kinds of modularity comes from **the independence one from the other** of the various modules, as seen most clearly in double dissociation.

At the outset my reading is there is a missing "of" between "independence" and "one", but when I tried to look closer I felt that this "one from the other" is standing alone not without a reason, so I went on to search Linggle, SKELL and COCA, which, with considerable hits, yielded such results as:

> Arden Green was a sprawling place, kitchen and garden far removed **one from the other**. 
> Both cases offer a unique experience **one from the other**.
> places during her life, none of them seemed too different, **one from the other**.
> These categories were said to be wholly distinct **one from the other**.
> Women are all different **one from the other**.

These examples strike me as evidence that "one from the other" might be an adverbial phrase in its own right, pointing to the possibility that I have found something trivial without realizing I'm reinventing the wheel. Therefore I referred to what dictionaries I have access to like M-W, OED, in whose entries I didn't find what I expected to, be it under "one", "from" or "other".

It seems now that adverbial "one from the other" exists, though occluded in large measure by its ordinary usage (like *differentiate one from the other*) in online corpora.

Apparently this is a phrase in use as an adverbial constituent, but not in a dictionary. I seek to confirm it being an adverbial phrase since dictionaries cannot help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adverb** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adverb)) A word that modifies a verb, adjective, other adverbs, or various other types of words, phrases, or clauses.

**Adjective** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adjective)) A word that modifies a noun or noun phrase or describes a noun’s referent.

Phrase 1

> Evidence for both kinds of modularity comes from the **independence one
> from the other** of **the various modules**, as seen most clearly in double
> dissociation.

"*Independence of the various modules*" is the noun phrase. "*Independence of the various modules one from the other*", "*one from the other*" is modifying an **NP**, so it is an adjective.

Phrase 2

> Arden Green was a sprawling place, kitchen and garden far removed
> **one from the other**.

"*Removed*" is an adjective, so "**one from the other**" is adverb here.

The same word or phrase can be both adjective or adverb depending on what it is modifying.

By applying this logic and deconstructing its(a sentence's) constituent parts it can be known whether the modifying word or phrase is adverbial or adjectival.